# Selected button color changes

Tags: swift, uicolor

Can anybody help me in changing the text color when user selected. Like I have three buttons on one viewcontroller and when users taps on 1 button it changes to white and the rest of two become grey.

Comment: create button using interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: using interface builder @ShebinKoshy

Comment: using xib/storyBoard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do same thing for all buttons in your interfaceBuilder

[image]

[image]

Then create outlet for all buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!    
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
```

Create action for all buttons

```
@IBAction func buttonOneAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    button1.selected = true;
    button2.selected = false;
    button3.selected = false;
}

@IBAction func buttonTwoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    button1.selected = false;
    button2.selected = true;
    button3.selected = false;
}

@IBAction func buttonThreeAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    button1.selected = false;
    button2.selected = false;
    button3.selected = true;
}
```

output: middle button is selected

[image]

Comment: I dont want this blue to come.Can this be avoided ? @ShebinKoshy

Comment: Sure.. do you have background color?

Comment: no it is set to default but the tint option is filled with blue

Comment: yeah if u set tint color as white, u can't visible the button. since ur text color and tint color and view's background color is white..

Comment: if your view's background color is not a white color, then u can set tint color as 'clear color'

Comment: Thank you alot my background color was black and now i changed my tint color to clear and its working great

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `setTitleColor(_:forState:)`.

```
// Setting the color for a button's disabled state to red

button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Disabled)
```

[UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:)

Comment: Where should i add this in viewdidload ? @M4TT

Comment: You can add the code to change the other buttons' colours in the IBAction when someone touches a button. For example, if someone touched "button 1" then in the IBAction that's called you'll change the colours for "button 2" and "button 3"

Comment: so like if i have 3 button and three IBActions so i have to add this 9 times by changing its state @M4TT

Comment: It seems so, or you could write a helper method to do it for you.